# React-native accordion / toggle functionality with slide animation

Tags: react-native

I want to have accordion / toggle functionality which will have slide or similar kind of animation

I have tried out this solution. But while closing animation do not work

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);       
            height: new Animated.Value(0)
        };

}

 _toggle = () => {   

            this.state.height.setValue(0);
            Animated.spring(
                this.state.height,
                {
                    toValue: expanded ? 200 : 0,
                    duration: 200
                }
            ).start();

}
```

Thanks in advance for your answers!!!

Answer (score 0):

The first line in `_toggle` sets the value to 0.

That's why when it's expanded, the animation goes from 0 to 0.
Removing that line should sort it.

Comment: If i remove that line, while opening animation works fine but while closing it toggles 2-3 times.

Comment: When you say it toggles 2-3 times, does that mean it fully opens and closes?

Comment: Yes, it does.. its strange why simple click causes it to toggle 2-3 times

Comment: Put a console.log in the function to make sure it is called more than once. Then, if it does, find where it is called in your code (is it only the click handler?). If there's only that place, perhaps it is getting triggered more than once for some reason?

Comment: Using Animated.timing solved my problem,
_toggle = () => {    
           
   Animated.timing(this.state.height, {
        toValue: expanded ? 200 : 0,
        easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.bezier(0.88, 0, 1, 1)),
        duration: 500
    }).start();     

} 

Thanks @Kraylog for help